# Rust inline assembly mov instruction copies wrong address

Tags: assembly, rust, operating-system, bios

I'm trying to write a simple freestanding program that prints a string to screen using BIOS interrupts.
The NASM-assembled version of my program is working fine.

However the Rust inline assembly version of it it's not because the `mov si, message` instruction gets translated to `mov si, word prt ds:0x7c34`.

The string location is correct (`0x7c34`), but after the mov instruction the si register content becomes `0x6548`. I don't know where this value comes from, but it's not the location of my string.

Here is my code:

main.rs

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;
use core::arch::global_asm;

global_asm!(include_str!("bootloader/boot.s"));

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

bootloader/boot.s

```
.section .boot, "awx"
.global _start
.code16

_start:
    jmp main

puts:
    push si
    push ax
    push bx

.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0
    int 0x10

    jmp .loop

.done:
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si    
    ret
    
main:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    cld

    mov sp, 0x7c00

    mov si, message
    call puts

spin:
    hlt
    jmp spin

message: .string "Hello world!"
```

build.rs

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let local_path = Path::new(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"));
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg-bins=--script={}", local_path.join("boot-link.ld").display())
}
```

boot-link.ld

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x500;
    _stack_start = .;
    . = 0x7c00;
    _stack_end = .;

    _mbr_start = .;
    .boot :
    {
        *(.boot .boot.*)
    }
    .text :
    {
        *(.text .text.*)
    }
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)
    }
    .data :
    {
        *(.rodata .rodata.*)
        *(.data .data.*)
        *(.got .got.*)
    }
    _mbr_end = .;

    . = 0x7c00 + 510;

    .magic_number :
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55)
    }

    _second_stage_start = .;
}
```

target.json

```
{
    "arch": "x86",
    "cpu": "i386",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-f64:32:64-f80:32-n8:16:32-S128",
    "dynamic-linking": false,
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "llvm-target": "i386-unknown-none-code16",
    "max-atomic-width": 64,
    "position-independent-executables": false,
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "target-pointer-width": "32",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "os": "none",
    "vendor": "unknown",
    "relocation-model": "static"
}
```

Then I'm using this command to shrink the executable:
`objcopy -I elf32-i386 -O binary target/x86_16-felix/debug/felix build/boot.bin`

Where I'm doing wrong?

I think the problem has something to do with the x86 addressing mode, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `0x6548` are the first two bytes of the "Hello ..." string. `mov si, message` is assembled as `mov si, WORD [message]` apparently. I'm not used to the Rust toolchain, what assembler are you using? It looks like gas, which wants `$` before immediates.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html) the Rust compiler uses "LLVM's internal assembler (syntax) which usually corresponds to that of the GNU assembler (GAS), on x86, the .intel_syntax noprefix mode of GAS is used by default"

Comment: … and you didn’t even use inline asm in your example…

Comment: @Miiao: Technically they did: `global_asm!(include_str!("bootloader/boot.s"));` inlines the `.s` into their Rust source instead of assembling it separately with GAS or clang.  (Or rustc?)  IDK what benefit that gets them apart from omitting `.intel_syntax noprefix`; seems silly.  In GNU C you'd use the same `asm()` keyword as you would inside a function, except inside a function you'd also use operand constraints unless it was a `naked` function.)  Rust's `global_asm` is a clear analogue of GNU C `asm()` statement at global scope, so it seems technically correct to call it inline asm.

Comment: @petercordes, it’s not. Inline asm is `core::arch::asm`, while `core::arch::global_asm` is global asm.

Comment: @Miiao: A reasonable person could loosely describe `global_asm` as a form of inline asm, inlining asm source into the source file even if not into a Rust function.  Those are different things, of course, but it's just a matter of terminology.  How would you describe `global_asm` in a way that distinguished it from a separate `.s` file?  Like "Rust global assembly" in the question title?  Fortunately instruction syntax `mov reg, OFFSET symbol` works the same in both.

Comment: @petercordes, the problem is that it’s actually not inlining anything - just putting contents into `.text`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using `lea si, message` instead of `mov si, message`

Comment: `lea` is larger than the correct `mov`. Probably you want `mov si, offset message`

Comment: @ecm: That's correct, GAS / clang `.intel_syntax noprefix` is MASM-like (except for directives), so `offset` is the trick here.  And yeah, LEA to put a symbol address in a register is always sub-optimal except in 64-bit mode with RIP-relative LEA if you need position-independence and/or being outside the low 4GiB of virtual address space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).